# how to deploy winform app with mdf file on server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2012

I have a winform app with a database running on sql server 2012. I want the app to work on multiple computers connected to a server in the local network.
I deployed the app using clickonce and moved the mdf file to the server.
Then I installed the app in a few computers and it works on every one of them separately however when the app runs on one computer and I try to open it on another one I get the following exception:

> Cannot open database (database name) requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'USER-PC\user'

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select 1", con))
                {
                    con.Open(); //exception thrown here
                    object returnValue = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (returnValue != null)
                        returnString = returnValue.ToString();

                    con.Close();
                }
```

The connection string is:

> Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFilename=path on server\database
>   name; Integrated Security=true;

I have tried to change attachdbfilename to Initial Catalog=database name, and add users to the db in ssms and add user id and password to the connection string. Nothing helped.
I'm afraid I have some basic concept misunderstood and doing it the wrong way.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please check/correct broken links between Login and DB-User with [sp_change_users_login](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174378(v=sql.120).aspx).